# linux computer blocks window os computers from accessing local wifi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I have been a linux user for the past one year.And I have noticed that all the distributions I have used so far have this trend of managing to block wifi access to windows computers on specific routers,though devices that have some sort of apple os continue to work fine..
By block , I mean these window computers aren't able to connect to the wifi(talk to it/make calls)

I was wondering if someone could tell me why such a trend is being observed or if it is just a coincidence.

I now am running ubuntu , earlier on it was sabayon,and then gentoo  and before that it was arch ..the problem seems to be independent of what distribution I use.

Usually the I have never had a problem, so I never bothered checking on any windows computer , the problem has affected windows users in the past who have mostly been room mates /house mates  ...but I have always wondered.

My network card vis a lshw is Intel Corporation's Centrino Wireless-N 1000

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [8086:0084]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1315]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at c3400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-26-c7-ff-ff-b2-b3-6c
--
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at c1404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at c1400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at c1410000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
```

Comment: I've mixed windows and Linux wifi clients for years with no sign of what you describe. is this always the same windows machine you are talking about?

Comment: You really don't describe the problem. What happens to the Windows computers that you describe as "blocked"? Do they still connect to the WiFi network? Can they still communicate with the router? Do they get assigned IP addresses?

Comment: What hardware are you on? What distributions?

Comment: Can you please post the Vendor+Device code of your wifi card? Ty

Comment: And, btw, yes, I have seen similar behaviour, but never with an Intel card. Broadcom wireless cards under Linux occasionally produce this kind of behaviour, when they use proprietary drivers; a switch to the open source driver b43 solves the problem. As for changing OS, this will not solve the problem because all wireless drivers are the same inside Linux, and many are actually in-kernel. Are you using iwlwifi as a driver?

Comment: Sure; lspci -vnn | grep -i net -A 8, pls post whole output

Comment: @MariusMatutiae output posted as a part of the question,as of now.